# C, Getting errors in symbolic constant definitions (possibly in function parameters)

Tags: c, gcc, syntax-error, constants

I have been getting this error in a C program that I'm writing:

```
progra10.c:48:25: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
#define LAST_INDEX ARRAY_SIZE - 1
```

and

```
program10.c:47:25: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
 #define ARRAY_SIZE       20
                         ^
program10.c:48:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘DATA_SIZE’
 #define LAST_INDEX      ARRAY_SIZE - 1
                         ^~~~~~~~~~
program10.c:64:42: note: in expansion of macro ‘LAST_INDEX’
 int  sequential_search(int seq_data, int LAST_INDEX, int search_target,
```

I use the GCC compiler with this command:

> gcc -Wall -ansi -oprogram10.exe program10.c -lm

This is the code that the error seems to be referring to:

```
#define COURSE_NUMBER "C Programming" /* Class */
#define PROGRAM_NUMBER 10 /* Program Number */
#define PROGRAMMER_NAME "Name" /* Programmer's Name */
#define ARRAY_SIZE 20 /* Size of the array */
#define LAST_INDEX ARRAY_SIZE - 1 /* The last index in the array */
```

I have no clue why it would be causing that error.  I've checked for open comments, tabs, open strings, among other things, and I have not been able to fix this error.  While compiling, this error is the only error, only it repeats for every time that LAST_INDEX is used in a function call parameter in main.  I know the rest of my program has errors, but the compilation doesn't even show them, leading me to believe that it can't get past this.

The functions look like this:

Function Prototype:

```
int  sequential_search(int seq_data, int LAST_INDEX, int search_target, 
                                                   int target_location);
```

Function Call:

```
sequential_search(seq_data, LAST_INDEX, search_target, target_location);
```

Function Definition:

```
int sequential_search(int seq_data, int LAST_INDEX, int search_target,
                                                    int target_location)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The error messages refer to line numbers like 47, 48, 64 — but there isn't that much code in the question.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses;
MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
One of the indicators of a reasonable question is that copying the code from the question generates the warnings claimed.  You're not there yet.

Comment: You're using the macros In the function declarations i.e. in both the function "prototype" and the function definition.    The function declaration looks to the compiler - after the preprocessor is done - like `int sequential_search(int seq_data, int 20 - 1, int search_target,  int target_location)`.    Only use that macro when calling the function, not in the argument list when declaring the function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to declare a function parameter call `LAST_INDEX`, but `LAST_INDEX` is defined as a macro, so expands to an expression.  The declarator for a function parameter needs to be a single identifier (the name you want to give the parameter), not an expression.